# Implement family tree visualization in Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, family-tree

I am trying to build a family tree with multiple generations using Python Graphviz. I've created functions to ease adding people using their relations (add married couple, add children). Though, I am facing an issue with Graphviz layout such that the edges are overlapping with the nodes when adding marriage and children. It seems like the married people nodes are not being drawn closely together as it should as shown below:

[image: sample tree]

As shown, the case for a couple with no children is perfect but when adding children, the layout seems to be confused.

Here is the layout without the second generation, the layout seems to be fine
[image: sample tree no 2nd generation]

The code that I am using to generate

```
import graphviz

def add_marriage_node(tree, id1, name1, id2, name2):
    with tree.subgraph() as sub_tree:
        sub_tree.attr(rank='same')
        sub_tree.node(str(id1), name1)
        sub_tree.node(str(id2), name2)
        sub_tree.node('N' + str(id1) + '_' + str(id2),
            shape='point',
            **{'width':str(0.08)})
    tree.edge(str(id1), 'N' + str(id1) + '_' + str(id2))
    tree.edge('N' + str(id1) + '_' + str(id2), str(id2))


# Children= [{'id': 1, 'name': 'ChildA'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ChildB'}]
def add_children_nodes(tree, father_id, mother_id, children):
    # Add parent_children point nodes
    with tree.subgraph() as sub_tree:
        sub_tree.attr(rank='same')
        for child in children:
            parent_node = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id)
            parent_child_node = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + '_' + str(child['id'])
            sub_tree.node(parent_child_node,
                shape='point',
                **{'width':str(0.08)})
        if len(children) % 2 == 0:
            center_node = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + 'B'
            sub_tree.node(center_node,
                    shape='point',
                    **{'width':str(0.08)})

    # Connect parent node to the middle parent_children point or a new center point
    if len(children) % 2 == 0:
        tree.edge(str(parent_node), str(center_node))
    else:
        middle_child = children[len(children) // 2]
        parent_child_node = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + '_' + str(middle_child['id'])
        tree.node(str(middle_child['id']), str(middle_child['name']))
        tree.edge(str(parent_node), str(parent_child_node))

    # Connect the parent_children nodes horizontally
    i = 0
    while i < len(children)-1:
        parent_child_node1 = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + '_' + str(children[i]['id'])
        parent_child_node2 = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + '_' + str(children[i+1]['id'])
        if len(children) % 2 == 0 and i == len(children)/2 - 1:
            tree.edge(parent_child_node1, center_node)
            tree.edge(center_node, parent_child_node2)
        else:
            tree.edge(parent_child_node1, parent_child_node2)
        i += 1

    # Add children nodes and connect them to their respective parent_children node
    for i in range(len(children)):
        parent_child_node = 'N' + str(father_id) + '_' + str(mother_id) + '_' + str(children[i]['id'])
        tree.node(str(children[i]['id']), str(children[i]['name']))
        tree.edge(parent_child_node, str(children[i]['id']))


tree = graphviz.Graph(  engine='dot',
                        graph_attr={
                                    'splines': 'false',
                                    'nodesep':'0.2',
                                    'ranksep': '0.125',
                                    'overlap':'false',
                                    'concentrate': 'false',
                                    'rankdir': 'TB'  # [TB, BT, LR, RL]
                        },
                        node_attr={'style': 'filled', 'shape': 'box'},
                        edge_attr={'dir': 'none', 'arrowhead': 'none'},
                        encoding='utf8',
                        filename='family_tree',
                        format='pdf')


add_marriage_node(tree, 1, 'Grand Father', 2, 'Grand Mother')

add_children_nodes(tree, 1, 2, [
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Father'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Uncle'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Aunt'},
    ])

add_marriage_node(tree, 3, 'Father', 6, 'Mother')
add_marriage_node(tree, 4, 'Uncle', 7, 'His Wife')
add_marriage_node(tree, 5, 'Aunt', 8, 'Her Husband')

add_children_nodes(tree, 3, 6, [
    {'id': 9, 'name': 'Me'},
    {'id': 10, 'name': 'Brother'},
    {'id': 11, 'name': 'Sister'},
    ])

add_marriage_node(tree, 9, 'Me', 12, 'My Wife')
add_children_nodes(tree, 9, 12, [
    {'id': 13, 'name': 'My Son'}
    ])

tree.view()
```

The dot file generated from the previous script:

```
graph {
    graph [concentrate=false nodesep=0.2 overlap=false rankdir=TB ranksep=0.125 splines=false]
    node [shape=box style=filled]
    edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
    {
        rank=same
        1 [label="Grand Father"]
        2 [label="Grand Mother"]
        N1_2 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    1 -- N1_2
    N1_2 -- 2
    {
        rank=same
        N1_2_3 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N1_2_4 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N1_2_5 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    4 [label=Uncle]
    N1_2 -- N1_2_4
    N1_2_3 -- N1_2_4
    N1_2_4 -- N1_2_5
    3 [label=Father]
    N1_2_3 -- 3
    4 [label=Uncle]
    N1_2_4 -- 4
    5 [label=Aunt]
    N1_2_5 -- 5
    {
        rank=same
        3 [label=Father]
        6 [label=Mother]
        N3_6 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    3 -- N3_6
    N3_6 -- 6
    {
        rank=same
        4 [label=Uncle]
        7 [label="His Wife"]
        N4_7 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    4 -- N4_7
    N4_7 -- 7
    {
        rank=same
        5 [label=Aunt]
        8 [label="Her Husband"]
        N5_8 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    5 -- N5_8
    N5_8 -- 8
    {
        rank=same
        N3_6_9 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N3_6_10 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N3_6_11 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    10 [label=Brother]
    N3_6 -- N3_6_10
    N3_6_9 -- N3_6_10
    N3_6_10 -- N3_6_11
    9 [label=Me]
    N3_6_9 -- 9
    10 [label=Brother]
    N3_6_10 -- 10
    11 [label=Sister]
    N3_6_11 -- 11
    {
        rank=same
        9 [label=Me]
        12 [label="My Wife"]
        N9_12 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    9 -- N9_12
    N9_12 -- 12
    {
        rank=same
        N9_12_13 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    13 [label="My Son"]
    N9_12 -- N9_12_13
    13 [label="My Son"]
    N9_12_13 -- 13
}
```

The main issue is the layout as stated above. Other issues are also present in the current implementation if you'd wish to further help are as listed below:

- Change the node shape to rounded corner box
- Formatting the node to have birth date, death date below the name with smaller font and an id with even smaller font at the bottom right corner of the node
- Children edge should connect to the center of the node such that the edge between the point shaped node and the child is of straight line
- Reducing the width of the point shape node shows discontinuity in the line rather than showing a continuous elbowed edge as I hoped

Any help would be greatly appreciated
If you think using Graphviz is a bad idea for building a family tree, please suggest other libraries

**----  UPDATE  ----**

Still finding trouble with scalability even after adding clusters and groups. When adding cousins, the layout again gets confused as shown in the tree below:

[image: sample tree 2]

Below is the dot generated from the python wrapper:

```
graph {
    graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
    node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
    edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
    subgraph cluster_1_2 {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true peripheries=0 ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        1 [label=<
                    Grand Father
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    1
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED"]
        2 [label=<
                    Grand Mother
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    2
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2"]
        N_1_2 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    1 -- N_1_2
    N_1_2 -- 2
    {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        N_1_2_3 [group=G_3 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_1_2_4 [group=G_4 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_1_2_5 [group=G_5 shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    4 [label=<
                    Aunt
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    4
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_4]
    N_1_2 -- N_1_2_4
    N_1_2_3 -- N_1_2_4
    N_1_2_4 -- N_1_2_5
    3 [label=<
                    Father
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    3
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_3]
    N_1_2_3 -- 3
    4 [label=<
                    Aunt
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    4
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_4]
    N_1_2_4 -- 4
    5 [label=<
                    Uncle
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    5
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_5]
    N_1_2_5 -- 5
    subgraph cluster_3_6 {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true peripheries=0 ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        3 [label=<
                    Father
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    3
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED"]
        6 [label=<
                    Mother
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    6
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2"]
        N_3_6 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    3 -- N_3_6
    N_3_6 -- 6
    subgraph cluster_5_8 {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true peripheries=0 ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        5 [label=<
                    Uncle
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    5
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED"]
        8 [label=<
                    His Wife
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    8
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2"]
        N_5_8 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    5 -- N_5_8
    N_5_8 -- 8
    subgraph cluster_4_7 {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true peripheries=0 ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        4 [label=<
                    Aunt
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    4
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2"]
        7 [label=<
                    Her Husband
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    7
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED"]
        N_4_7 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    4 -- N_4_7
    N_4_7 -- 7
    {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        N_3_6_9 [group=G_9 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_3_6_10 [group=G_10 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_3_6_11 [group=G_11 shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    10 [label=<
                    Sister
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    10
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_10]
    N_3_6 -- N_3_6_10
    N_3_6_9 -- N_3_6_10
    N_3_6_10 -- N_3_6_11
    9 [label=<
                    Me
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    9
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_9]
    N_3_6_9 -- 9
    10 [label=<
                    Sister
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    10
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_10]
    N_3_6_10 -- 10
    11 [label=<
                    Brother
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    11
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_11]
    N_3_6_11 -- 11
    {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        N_4_7_14 [group=G_14 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_4_7_15 [group=G_15 shape=point width=0.08]
        N4_7B [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    N_4_7 -- N4_7B
    N_4_7_14 -- N4_7B
    N4_7B -- N_4_7_15
    14 [label=<
                    Cousin 1
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    14
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_14]
    N_4_7_14 -- 14
    15 [label=<
                    Cousin 2
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    15
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_15]
    N_4_7_15 -- 15
    {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        N_5_8_16 [group=G_16 shape=point width=0.08]
        N_5_8_17 [group=G_17 shape=point width=0.08]
        N5_8B [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    N_5_8 -- N5_8B
    N_5_8_16 -- N5_8B
    N5_8B -- N_5_8_17
    16 [label=<
                    Cousin 3
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    16
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2" group=G_16]
    N_5_8_16 -- 16
    17 [label=<
                    Cousin 4
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    17
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_17]
    N_5_8_17 -- 17
    subgraph cluster_9_12 {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true peripheries=0 ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        9 [label=<
                    Me
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    9
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED"]
        12 [label=<
                    My Wife
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    12
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#F4C2C2"]
        N_9_12 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    9 -- N_9_12
    N_9_12 -- 12
    {
        graph [concentrate=false newrank=true ranksep=0.1 splines=false]
        node [shape=box style="filled, rounded"]
        edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
        rank=same
        N_9_12_13 [group=G_13 shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    13 [label=<
                    My Son
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    13
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_13]
    N_9_12 -- N_9_12_13
    13 [label=<
                    My Son
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="9">
                    1900 - 1950
                    </FONT>
                    <BR/>
                    <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">
                    13
                    </FONT>
                    <BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>
                    > fillcolor="#C2EBED" group=G_13]
    N_9_12_13 -- 13
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: first create a test input file in "straight" dot language. Then edit that file to experiment with various dot attributes.  Finally, when you are happy, figure out how to create that using Python.  Or maybe find a "family tree" software package.

Comment: @sroush I tried that but still unsuccessful to achieve the targeted result. I have added the dot file that was generated through the python script just in case it helps with my question

Comment: Graphviz as such is not a bad idea, but instead of generating the .dot file with Python (or any other language), the first approach should be to "hand-craft" it – and afterwards, using a generator. As an alternative to Graphviz, you should have a look to SVG.

Comment: @tquadrat Since I am developing a large structure, I won't be able to manually build the dot file. The mentioned structure is a dummy structure that does not actually reflect the end structure. This is why Python is used. Regarding an alternative generator, could you please clarify what you mean cause having an output in an SVG format or any other which is all provided by Graphviz, does not alter in anyway the layout stucture.

Comment: @Youstanzr what python wrapper are you using?

Comment: @Flow its been a while but if I recall correctly, this is what I am using: https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @Youstanzr Thank you for answering is there anyway I can have the python code you used to generate the 2 graph?

Comment: @Flow It is already available in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had many leading spaces in your label text.  The resulting node width caused(?) the odd placement.  Here is your graph with spaces removed, but names padded to believable length:

```
graph {
    graph [concentrate=false,
        newrank=true,
        ranksep=0.1,
        splines=false
    ];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=box,
        style="filled, rounded"
    ];
    edge [arrowhead=none,
        dir=none
    ];
    {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        N_1_2_3 [group=G_3,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_1_2_4 [group=G_4,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_1_2_5 [group=G_5,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
    }
    {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        N_3_6_9 [group=G_9,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_3_6_10    [group=G_10,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_3_6_11    [group=G_11,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
    }
    {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        N_4_7_14    [group=G_14,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_4_7_15    [group=G_15,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N4_7B   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
    }
    {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        N_5_8_16    [group=G_16,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N_5_8_17    [group=G_17,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        N5_8B   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
    }
    {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        N_9_12_13   [group=G_13,
            shape=point,
            width=0.08];
    }
    subgraph cluster_1_2 {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            peripheries=0,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        1   [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
    label=<Grand Father<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">1</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_1_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        1 -- N_1_2;
        2   [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
    label=<Grand Mother<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">2</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_1_2 -- 2;
    }
    subgraph cluster_3_6 {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            peripheries=0,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        3   [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
            group=G_3,
    label=<Father Father<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">3</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_3_6   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        3 -- N_3_6;
        6   [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
    label=<Mother Mother<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">6</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_3_6 -- 6;
    }
    subgraph cluster_5_8 {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            peripheries=0,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        5   [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
            group=G_5,
    label=<Uncle Uncleeeee<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">5</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_5_8   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        5 -- N_5_8;
        8   [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
    label=<His Wife Wife<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">8</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_5_8 -- 8;
    }
    subgraph cluster_4_7 {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            peripheries=0,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        4   [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
            group=G_4,
    label=<Auntie Auntie<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">4</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_4_7   [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        4 -- N_4_7;
        7   [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
    label=<Her Husband Husband<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">7</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_4_7 -- 7;
    }
    subgraph cluster_9_12 {
        graph [concentrate=false,
            newrank=true,
            peripheries=0,
            rank=same,
            ranksep=0.1,
            splines=false
        ];
        node [shape=box,
            style="filled, rounded"
        ];
        edge [arrowhead=none,
            dir=none
        ];
        9   [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
            group=G_9,
    label=<Call Me Ishmael<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">9</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_9_12  [shape=point,
            width=0.08];
        9 -- N_9_12;
        12  [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
    label=<My Wife Wife<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">12</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N_9_12 -- 12;
    }
    N_1_2 -- N_1_2_4;
    N_1_2_3 -- N_1_2_4;
    N_1_2_3 -- 3;
    N_1_2_4 -- N_1_2_5;
    N_1_2_4 -- 4;
    N_1_2_5 -- 5;
    N_3_6 -- N_3_6_10;
    N_5_8 -- N5_8B;
    N_4_7 -- N4_7B;
    N_3_6_9 -- N_3_6_10;
    N_3_6_9 -- 9;
    N_3_6_10 -- N_3_6_11;
    10  [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
        group=G_10,
    label=<Sister Sister<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">10</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_3_6_10 -- 10;
    11  [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
        group=G_11,
    label=<Brother Brother<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">11</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_3_6_11 -- 11;
    N_4_7_14 -- N4_7B;
    14  [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
        group=G_14,
    label=<Cousin 1 Cousin<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">14</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_4_7_14 -- 14;
    15  [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
        group=G_15,
    label=<Cousin 2 Cousin<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">15</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_4_7_15 -- 15;
    N4_7B -- N_4_7_15;
    N_5_8_16 -- N5_8B;
    16  [fillcolor="#F4C2C2",
        group=G_16,
    label=<Cousin 3 Cousin<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">16</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_5_8_16 -- 16;
    17  [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
        group=G_17,
    label=<Cousin 4 Cousin<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">17</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_5_8_17 -- 17;
    N5_8B -- N_5_8_17;
    N_9_12 -- N_9_12_13;
    13  [fillcolor="#C2EBED",
        group=G_13,
    label=<My Son the Kid<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1900 - 1950</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">13</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
    N_9_12_13 -- 13;
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Regarding the leading spaces, apparently when the file is viewed using python, it does not show those spaces but an online graphviz engine shows them. Since I am generating using python, then this is of no issue to me. Regarding the fixed layout, it seems that it was fixed due to the reordering of the subgraphs to be at the top for some reason. Once you have the dot file order as subgraphs -> clusters -> edges, then the issue is fixed but the regular order I had them seems to be confusing the engine somehow. Any ideas why this would happen and how it would be fixed without obeying the order?

Comment: Input sequence often affects the output.  You might try a second cluster "layer" combining all siblings (with spousal cluster(s) inside)

Answer (score 2):

Used **clusters**, **group** attribute and **html-like** labels.  Peripheries can be set to 0 if desired (see example)

```
graph {
    graph [concentrate=false nodesep=0.2 overlap=false rankdir=TB ranksep=0.125 splines=false]
    node [shape=box style="filled,rounded"]  // added rounded
    edge [arrowhead=none dir=none]
    // added clusters to group couples
    // used group attribute (to nodes) to make connector edges vertical
    {
        rank=same
    // example of mult-line & justified, same fontsize
        1 [label="Grand Father\n1/2/1610-1/3/1810\nabc\r"]
    // example using "html-like" label
    //   see:   https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html
        2 [label=<Grand Mother<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="9">1/2/1610-1/3/1810</FONT><BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="7">read me</FONT><BR ALIGN="RIGHT"/>>]
        N1_2 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    1 -- N1_2
    N1_2 -- 2
    {
        rank=same
        N1_2_3 [shape=point width=0.08 group=F]
        N1_2_4 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N1_2_5 [shape=point width=0.08 group=A]
    }
    4 [label=Uncle]
    N1_2 -- N1_2_4
    N1_2_3 -- N1_2_4
    N1_2_4 -- N1_2_5
    3 [label=Father]
    N1_2_3 -- 3 
    4 [label=Uncle]
    N1_2_4 -- 4
    5 [label=Aunt group=A]
    N1_2_5 -- 5
    subgraph cluster1{
      graph [peripheries=0]  // no surrounding rectangle
      {
        rank=same
        3 [label=Father group=F]
        6 [label=Mother]
        N3_6 [shape=point width=0.08]
      }
    }
    3 -- N3_6
    N3_6 -- 6
    subgraph clusterU{
      {
        rank=same
        4 [label=Uncle]
        7 [label="His Wife"]
        N4_7 [shape=point width=0.08]
      }
    }
    4 -- N4_7
    N4_7 -- 7
    subgraph clusteraeiou {
      {
        rank=same
        5 [label=Aunt]
        8 [label="Her Husband"]
        N5_8 [shape=point width=0.08]
      }
    }
    5 -- N5_8
    N5_8 -- 8
    {
        rank=same
        N3_6_9 [shape=point width=0.08 group=g9]
        N3_6_10 [shape=point width=0.08]
        N3_6_11 [shape=point width=0.08 group=g10]  // group: try to make N3_6_11 -- 11  vertical
    }
    10 [label=Brother]
    N3_6 -- N3_6_10
    N3_6_9 -- N3_6_10
    N3_6_10 -- N3_6_11
    9 [label=Me]
    N3_6_9 -- 9
    10 [label=Brother]
    N3_6_10 -- 10
    11 [label=Sister group=g10]  // group: try to make N3_6_11 -- 11  vertical
    N3_6_11 -- 11
    subgraph cluster0{
      {
        rank=same
        9 [label=Me  group=g9]
        12 [label="My Wife"]
        N9_12 [shape=point width=0.08]
      }
    }
    9 -- N9_12
    N9_12 -- 12
    {
        rank=same
        N9_12_13 [shape=point width=0.08]
    }
    13 [label="My Son"]
    N9_12 -- N9_12_13
    13 [label="My Son"]
    N9_12_13 -- 13
}
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: This worked on the dot file I posted  but the concept did not scale well when cousins were added. I have updated the question to show this new layout issue.